# Is there a difference between single and double quotes in Java?

Tags: java, syntax

Is there a difference between single and double quotes in Java?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Use single quotes for literal `char`s, double quotes for literal `String`s, like so:

```
char c = 'a';
String s = "hello";
```

They cannot be used any other way around (like in Python, for example).

Comment: And, of course, this behavior is borrowed from C (which probably got it somewhere else, I presume).

Comment: For me, apostrophes literal automatically casted to `int` in such contexts. So it doesn't need to be `char`. Deservin' some downvotes... simplistic.

Comment: @Klaider can you elaborate on that? Would some characters not cast to a char?

Comment: @ngood97 My comment was rather wishing apostrophes automatically adapted to `int` in Java (`int c = 'a';`), but it's outdated. Actually, my ECMAScript dialect has string literal automatically adapting to `Char` (`var ch:Char = "a";`).

Comment: Oh so java doesn't in fact cast character literals to int. Which ECMAScript dialect does this syntax you're referring to btw?

Comment: @ngood97 [DoveScript](https://github.com/dovescript/developernetwork/blob/master/demo/Enumerations.md), but the compiler doesn't still have a target and haven't implemented the runtime.

Answer (score 43):

A char is a single UTF-16 character, that is a letter, a digit, a punctuation mark, a tab, a space or something similar.

A char literal is either a single one character enclosed in single quote marks like this

```
char myCharacter = 'g';
```

or an escape sequence, or even a unicode escape sequence:

```
char a = '\t';    // Escape sequence: tab
char b = '\177'   // Escape sequence, octal.
char c = '\u03a9' // Unicode escape sequence.
```

It is worth noting that Unicode escape sequences are processed very early during compilation and hence using '\u00A' will lead to a compiler error. For special symbols it is better to use escape sequences instead, i.e. '\n' instead of '\u00A' .

Double quotes being for `String`, you have to use a "double quote escape sequence" (`\"`) inside strings where it would otherwise terminate the string.
For instance:

```
System.out.println("And then Jim said, \"Who's at the door?\"");
```

It isn't necessary to escape the double quote inside single quotes.
The following line is legal in Java:

```
char doublequote = '"';
```

Answer (score 22):

Let's consider this lines of code (Java):

```
System.out.println("H"+"A"); //HA
System.out.println('H'+'a'); //169
```

1. First line is concatenation of `H` and `A` that will result in `HA` (String literal)
2. Second we are adding the values of two char that according to the ASCII Table `H`=72 and `a`=97 that means that we are adding `72+97` it's like `('H'+'a')`.
3. Let's consider another case where we would have:

   System.out.println("A"+'N');//AN

In this case we are dealing with concatenation of String `A` and char `N` that will result in `AN`.

Answer (score 5):

Single quote indicates character and double quote indicates string..

char c='c';

'c'-----> c is a character

String s="stackoverflow";

"stackoverflow"------> stackoverflow is a string(i.e collection if characters)