# What is the difference between " " and ' '?

Tags: java, string, char

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a difference between single and double quotes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439485/is-there-a-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-java)

I've seen some code which uses the ' ' version to subtract character values from each other which I didn't think was possible which got thinking as to what exactly they infer that is different?

**What is the difference between " " and ' '?** (How do they change how the code sees what ever is within the apostrophes / quotation marks etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is a matter of type. `" "` is a string literal, a Java String containing only a space character, and `' '` is a character literal, or a literal Java `char`. The String could contain 1 `char`, 2, 3, or more, and Strings are made up of an underlying array of `char` values like `' '`.

Answer (score 1):

Single quoted variables such as `' '` are interpreted as a `char`, whereas double quoted variables such as `" "` is a `String`.