# char datatype and returning a letter v number

Tags: java

I've got this method here:

```
public char charAt(int location) {
    //TODO Finish method
    return "a";
}
```

which I've added return `"a"` just to test the char datatype as I'm a student and new to java.
I am getting an error from Eclipse telling me to convert to String. Is `"A"` not a `character`?

It will return 1; no problems, but it won't take a single letter `character`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Should be

```
public char charAt(int location) {
    //TODO Finish method
    return 'a';
}
```

Not `"` quotes , should be `'`

Prefer to read :[Is there a difference between single and double quotes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439485/is-there-a-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-java)

Comment: that's a reason for upvote? I'd say: upvote because it is correct.

Comment: +1 for having the patience to answer this instead of saying "RTFM" :-)

Answer (score 2):

Everything in `"doublequotes"` is treated as string by the compiler.
If you want a character use single quotes: `'a'`.

Why `return "a";` is not working but `return 1`; is:

int can be converted to char.
string cannot be (automatically) converted to char.

Answer (score 1):

it should be `'a'` instead of `"a"` . Double quotes represent `String` while single quotes represent `char`. So your code should be

```
public char charAt(int location) {
    //TODO Finish method
    return 'a';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are returning a string instead of char

do this way

```
public char charAt(int location) {
    //TODO Finish method
    return 'a';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  public char charAt(int location) {
            //TODO Finish method
            String str ="a";  // actual string could be different 
            return str.charAt(location);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a char use follows

```
 public char charAt(int location) { //return char       
    return 'a';
    }
```

Or

```
public int charAt(int location) {   //return  int value of char
  return 'a';
}
```