# Why does Java require the char variable to use single quotes?

Tags: java, syntax

Why is it that Java requires the char variable to enclose anything inside of it with single quotes rather than double? An example of this:

```
char s = 's'; //This will not break
```

vs:

```
char s = "s"; //This will break
```

I understand that double quotes are primarily for strings but is there a specific reason as to why chars were built to only use single quotes and to break when a double quote is entered?

I have tried to do some research but the only thing that was relevant was another SO [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439485/is-there-a-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-java), which refers to the difference between single and double quotes, not the reasoning behind the syntactical development of the char.

Comment: Because that's how the language is defined?  I'm not sure there's any deep insight here...

Comment: Maybe so that it is similar to `c`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c

Comment: Its the same as 3.1 and 3.1f for doubles and floats. There just had to be some way to mark the difference and that was what was chosen

Comment: You use single quotes with char **literals**, not with char variables. And so the question comes down to why is the lexical syntax like it is?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because `char` and `String` are two different types, and how else is Java supposed to know whether you want a character or string of length 1?

For example, given the methods:

```
public void foo(String s) { }
public void foo(char c) { }
```

And the call

```
foo("a");
```

If characters could be made with double quotes, how would Java know which method to call?

Comment: Yeah you can't get a more accurate answer than this.

Comment: This pretty much explains it... I wasn't sure if there was any other specific reasoning behind the development of Java set aside from the ability to differentiate between char and string.

Comment: @BuddhistBeast I think this one is enough specific :)

Comment: I would rather java let me use single or double quotes for strings and chars(if I choose) and suffer having to do `foo((char) "a");` in places where type inference cant do that for me.

Comment: @ZouZou, I completely agree. I just was not sure if there was any other reasoning behind it.

Comment: @rambocoder Really? So you would prefer `((String) 'The variable is ') + someIntVar + ((String) '.')`?

Comment: @rambo that would be horrific for any optimisation, chars are primative and quick; what you propose could cause a large (and wholey unnecessary) garbage collection problem for any program using lots of chars

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow no, I think strings should be the default for both quote styles since strings are orders of magnitude more common than char.

Comment: @rambocoder ...which would **drastically** slow down any program using `char`s.

Comment: @RichardTingle I think it could all be done at compile time. Again, type inference can solve most of it without the programmer needing to do explicit type labeling (like how we suffix a long literal).

Comment: @rambo why? Why does string need two ways to write it? Thats like saying 3.0 and 3.0f should both give doubles because doubles are more common. The sole purpose of the single quote is to indicate chars, if chars didn't exist there would be no single quote

Comment: @rambocoder So you're basically proposing something like `"a"c` -> char, `"a"` -> String? That would be weird, as no C based languages do that AFAIK, and ugly.

Comment: @RichardTingle because `"this is a common \"ugly and hard to read\" java string";` but `'this is "much" better';`. again, this is just my desire. even better would be a different quote altogether, like `"""anything goes""";`

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow ya a suffix like that would be decent, imo.

Comment: @rambocoder That's not "ugly and hard to read"; that's a normal and pretty obvious to read string literal any C/C++ programmer (or any C-based lang programmer) would see. The second one would look odd in a C-based language, and the third is just... I don't even

Answer (score 2):

This is a question written by a person used to the modern easy scripting languages whose goal is to make programming easy to learn and fast to type.

Java is a language for people who know what the CPU does underneath. In the world of low level languages (assembley, C, Java etc.) a character is an integer (UTF may require more than one int) whereas a string is an array of integers. By allowing a programmer to define the exact variable type, Java allows you to write more efficient code.

But it also allows you to write String s = "s"; if you don't care about efficiency.

Comment: ummmmm... what? How does this answer the question exactly?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. BuddhistBeast isn't asking why `char` and `String` are two separate things - they're asking why char literals can only be created with single-quotes, and string literals only with double-quotes.

Comment: "Java is a language for people who know what the CPU does underneath."  There's a bit of truth to that, but humorous none the less, given the JVM.

Comment: A virtual machine makes coding easier but it does not mean that a good programmer may be ignorant.

Comment: What are you talking about? Please enclose the question in your answer!!!