# I can use char[],and can't use String[] with Cyrillic alphabet. Why?

Tags: java, arrays

When I use:

```
char[] abcCyr = {'a','б','в','г','д','ё','ж','з','и','к','л','м','н','п','р','с','т','у','ў','ф','х','ц','ш','щ','ы','ю','я'};
```

Nothing is wrong, but when I try to change type of array to String, eclipse forbid me to do this. What is wrong?

Comment: Char literals use single quotes. String literals use double.

Comment: How about showing us the code that doesn't compile, with the error message you get, rather than showing us the code that doesn't have any problem? You want us to guess what the problem is?

Comment: Here usefull answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439485/is-there-a-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`'a'` is `char`

`"a"` is `String`

In order to use `String`:

```
String[] abcCyr = {"a", "б","в"}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
char[] abcCyr = {'a','б','в'};
String[] abc = {"abc","def","ghi"};
```

`char` is a primitive type. `String` is a class.

Comment: @Maroun Maroun thnks for editing.