# Java Beginner: Why Does char Use ' ' Instead of " "?

Tags: java

Is there a specific reason `' '` is used for `char` in Java programming?

It may be a stupid question, but I would like to know exactly ***why***.

Comment: "" is used for Strings

Comment: '' is used for declaring char literals while "" is used for String literals

Comment: James Gosling may be able to answer this.

Comment: I'm guessing it's history and precedence inherited from C.  To know "exactly" why you'll have to ask James Gosling.  Anything else posted here is speculation and conjecture.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because a `string` uses double quotes and it needs to differentiate between a `char` and a `string`.

Just the same as it requires you adding an `L` for `long` and an `f` for float when specifying numbers - it needs to be able to determine which type you are referring to.

This is a [very good article](http://www.jchq.net/certkey/0406certkey.htm) on declaring string literals in Java.

Comment: More @ [*this answer*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/439551/767881)

Comment: @Ravinder thanks for the link. I'm going to go back to it.

Comment: @RGraham the link you posted. I'm going to save it for future reference. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If your question is,

> Why not use the double quote both for String and char?

then the answer is unambiguous: `'a'` is a completely different thing than `"a"`.

If, on the other hand, your question is more on the line of

> Why did Java choose to use the single quote for char, instead of something which I would prefer?

then there is no unique (or interesting) answer. The original designers of Java chose the single quote; for comparison, Rich Hickey chose a backslash prefix for Clojure and it works just as well.

Comment: The last one was the one I was really trying to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Its just to differentiate between a single character and a String. This method started with `C` and is continued to `java`.

Answer (score 1):

`''` is used for Characters for the main reason of differentiating between Strings (Which use `""` instead of `''`).

A cool little trick to remember which type uses which type of quotation, remember how Strings can have more than one Character in them (Which is why they use a 'double' quote). Characters on the other hand, are basically an integer value that can be displayed as a single character (Essentially a letter) which is why they have the 'single' quote.