# Why does ('1'+'1') output 98 in Java?

Tags: java, system.out, custom-data-type

I have the following code:

```
class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        System.out.println('1'+'1');

    }
}
```

Why does it output `98`?

Comment: Related: [In Java, is the result of the addition of two chars an int or a char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688668/in-java-is-the-result-of-the-addition-of-two-chars-an-int-or-a-char) I suspect that this question is a duplicate. I haven’t found the exact original yet.

Comment: Which output had you expected (if you had any expectations)? 2? 11? A compile-time error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a difference between single and double quotes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439485/is-there-a-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-java)

Comment: Also see [Concatenate chars to form String in java](//stackoverflow.com/q/16282368), which tells you how to build a string from char.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In java, every character literal is associated with an ASCII value which is an `Integer`.

You can find all the ASCII values [here](https://ascii.cl/)

`'1'` maps to ASCII value of 49 (`int` type). 
thus `'1'` + `'1'` becomes `49 + 49` which is an integer 98.

If you cast this value to `char` type as shown below, it will print ASCII value of 98 which is `b`

`System.out.println( (char) ('1'+'1') );`

If you are aiming at concatenating 2 chars (meaning, you expect `"11"` from your example), consider converting them to string first. Either by using double quotes, `"1" + "1"` or as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8172420/8283737) .

Answer (score 6):

`'1'` is a `char` literal, and the `+` operator between two `char`s returns an `int`. The character `'1'`'s unicode value is 49, so when you add two of them you get 98.

Comment: Char literals look like single character strings but aren’t.

Answer (score 4):

`'1'` denotes a character and evaluates to the corresponding ASCII value of the character, which is 49 for `1`. Adding two of them gives 98.

Answer (score 3):

49 is the ASCII value of 1. So `'1' +'1'` is equal to `49 + 49 = 98`.

Answer (score 1):

`'1'` is chat literal and it’s represent ASCII value which is 49 so sum of `'1'+'1'=98`.

Here I am sharing `ASCII` table as image. If you count column wise start from 0 so `1` is comes at 49th place. Sorry I am attaching image for better explanation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`'1'` is a `char` literal, and the + operator between two chars returns an int. The character '1''s unicode value is 49, so `49 + 49` equals 98.