# I am stuck in this assignment in Java. Can someone pls help me

Tags: java

I have finished most codes, but now I am stuck at how to use boolean to decide if the customer is qualified for a discount.

```
        System.out.print("Enter invoice number: ");
        int invoiceNum = console.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
        String firstName = console.next();

        System.out.print("Enter last name: ");
        String lastName = console.next();

        System.out.println("Is the customer qualified for a discount? (Y or N): ");
        String qualified = console.next();

        System.out.print("Enter discount rate ( ex. 12 for 12%): ");
        double discountRate = console.nextDouble();

        return new Service(invoiceNum, firstName,lastName, true/*???*/, discountRate);
```

```
 @Override
    public double calculateCost(){
        if(super.isIsQualifiedDiscount() == true){
            double total = serviceCharge * (1 - (super.getDiscountRate() / 100));
            System.out.printf("%nInspection Charge with Discount: %.2f", total);
            return total;
        }
        else{
        return serviceCharge;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Inspection Service Charge: " + serviceCharge;
    }
```

How should I connect these two parts so I can use Y or N to decide it??
below is my assignment picture:``
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg5ux.png)

Comment: You say you need a boolean, so why is `qualified` a String? Shouldn't it be a `boolean` type?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a difference between single and double quotes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439485/is-there-a-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-java)

Comment: Note: be aware of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/85421) in case a `nextLine()` is introduced

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```java
boolean isQualified = qualified.toLowerCase().equals("y")
```

**Edit:**

As suggested in the comment by @user85421, alternate and better approach would be

```java
boolean isQualified = qualified.equalsIgnoreCase("y")
```

Comment: `equalsIgnoreCase` would be more appropriate IMO

Answer (score 0):

As per your problem statement, the service class should include getter and setter methods for your data members. The status of discount qualification should be a boolean variable in your service class. 
Thus, once you read the input from the console you can use the below code to set the value to your boolean variable.

```
String discountStatus = sc.next();
setQualified(status.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
```

Now in your calculateCost() method, you call your Base Class method isQualified() to evaluate condition.

```
    if(isQualified()){
      // business logic
    }
```