# Question about java String "hello" and 'hello'

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist

Why this is invalid in java?

```
List<String> items=new ArrayList<String>();
items.add("hello"); // valid
items.add('hello'); // invalid (error: invalid character constants)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a difference between single and double quotes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439485/is-there-a-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `''` single quotes are used for `char` variables.
Meaning `'a'`, `'b'`, and so on. So only one character per variable.

The double quotes on the other side `""` are used to initialize `String` variables, which are several characters gathered together into one variable e.g `"i am a string"`

```java
char c = 'c' // I use single quotes because I am single :)
String str = "This is a string" // I use double quotes because I got a lot in me
```